# how can I git cherry-pick a commit from branch A to branch B but I am in branch master?

Tags: git

I need cherry-pick a commit from DEV to master, INT(for internal test environment), PROD branches.

If I need switch to corresponding branch every time cherry-pick, then I need checkout INT, checkout PROD.

Can I just be in branch Master and cherry-pick a commit from DEV to INT, to PROD but without checkout to any other branch?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general, no.  Cherry-picking is implemented as a kind of merge internally, and merging—like most processes in Git—takes place on the *current branch*, so the branch must be checked out in a working tree, with an index in which the merge can happen.

You can, however, *add* a *new working tree* to any existing Git repository using `git worktree add`.  This new working tree must be on some other branch: not the branch checked out in the main working tree, and not any branch checked out in any other working tree.<sup>1</sup>  But that is exactly what you want here.  So just add one working tree that's on branch `INT`—this becomes your second working tree—and a third one that's on branch `PROD`, and do the two cherry-pick operations in the two added working trees.

---

<sup>1</sup>A working tree can also be in "detached HEAD" mode, but this doesn't help for your case.